# Independence betweeen sets of random variables

Tags: random-variable, independence, distributions

Given two random variables $A$ and $B$, I know we can call them independent if their joint PDF is factorizable to a product of their marginal PDFs:

$f_{A,B}\left(A,B\right)=f_{A}\left(A\right)\cdot f_{B}\left(B\right)$

My problem: I have two *sets* of random variables, $\mathcal{S}_1=\left\{A,B \right\}$ and $\mathcal{S}_2=\left\{C,D \right\}$. I'd like to be able to show that the first set of random variables is independent of the second. I don't care about the relationship between $A$ and $B$, and the relationship between $C$ and $D$. Intuitively, I would understand "independence" here to mean that, given a single realization of all four random variables, the value of the realization for the first two will give me no additional help in predicting the value of the realization for the second two. Strictly speaking, it seems to me that this is equivalent to showing that the four-dimensional joint PDF factorizes to a product of the two two-dimensional PDFs:

$f_{A,B,C,D}\left(A,B,C,D\right)=f_{A,B}\left(A,B\right)\cdot f_{C,D}\left(C,D\right)$

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct (modulo a few typographical mistakes)
provided you get away from having the arguments of the PDFs be the same as the subscripts. The arguments are real variables; the subscripts are *random* variables and no, they don't even need to have the same letters in different cases (upper vs lower) or fonts.  What you need to write for complete correctness is
$$f_{A,B}\left(x,y\right)=f_{A}\left(x\right)\cdot f_{B}\left(y\right),
\quad -\infty < x, y < \infty$$
and
$$f_{A,B,C,D}\left(w,x,y,z\right)
=f_{A,B}\left(w,x\right)\cdot f_{C,D}\left(y,z\right),
\quad -\infty < w, x, y, z < \infty$$
where those comments following the equalities are very important. The
joint density must be expressible as the product of the marginal densities at *every* point in $\mathcal R^2$ and $\mathcal R^4$ respectively.

Comment: Appreciate the typographical corrections. I always thought it was a bit verbose to repeat the random variables as function arguments given that they were already there as subscripts.

Comment: As the late Robert Ash wrote in the preface of his _[Basic Probability Theory](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf)_ "$P\{X\leq x\}$ is written for the probability that the random variable $X$ assumes a value less than or equal to the number $x~\ldots~$ as the semester progressed, the capital $X$ tended to become smaller in the students' written work and the small $x$ larger $\ldots$" and I have observed this phenomenon far too many times myself. By the way, how would one read aloud $P\{X\leq x\}$ is a classroom setting? "the probability that big ecks is no larger than small ecks"?